# Showing COUNTIF results in a Message Box

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am currently using this code to display the number of "RCA Pending" found in a column. The message box does show the correct number of times it is found in the column, however, it creates a box for each instance (i.e. if there are 2 instances in the column, when the workbook is open it will display "Found 2 RCA Pending(s)", then when the user clicks OK, a second popup saying the same thing appears. If there are 5, you will get 5 consecutive popups).

```
Sub Auto_Open()

    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In Worksheets("Swivel").UsedRange.Rows
        If row.Cells(1, "AB").Value = "RCA Pending" Then
            MsgBox "Found " & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("AB"), "RCA Pending") & " RCA Pending(s)", vbInformation, "RCA Pending Found"
        End If
    Next row

End Sub
```

How can this be altered to show the total number of instances and not get multiple popups?

As a side note, I am using UsedRange because the range is always growing. The module that this code resides in has `Option Explicit` at the top.

Comment: Why are you using the loop at all?  It looks like you started one way then changed tactics.  Get rid of the loop and the IF statement only have the message box.

Comment: You could do an `exit for` after the `MsgBox` line but as scott pointed out could just do a find or something instead of the loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner The intent of the IF statement was to prevent the popup if there are zero instances. I will try this and provide feedback.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I just saw your comment. I have deleted my answer. I would recommend that you put that as an answer.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I was waiting for a response from the OP. By the time he/she responded you had answered.  Feel free to undelete your answer I am not a glutton for points, only to help.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Ditto here and hence I deleted my answer ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Actually, your answer worked perfectly. The first part you posted. Is there another way of doing this without an IF statement? If there are no instances of "RCA Pending" in the column, I do not want a popup message, and only one popup no matter how many instances there are. Your answer did that.

Comment: @IronMan: I believe Scott will post and answer soon :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I did not mean to imply you were a glutton, I can see how my comment could have been read that way.  I am feeling lazy today.  Please let's use yours.

Comment: @ScottCraner When I removed the IF statement and For Loop, I did get the popup when there were no instances of RCA Pending in the column (and the message stated that correctly).

Comment: As you wish @ScottCraner. I un deleted my answer

Comment: @ScottCraner and it is he, btw...lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim instances As Long

    instances = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("AB"), "RCA Pending")

    If instances <> 0 Then _
    MsgBox "Found " & instances & " RCA Pending(s)", vbInformation, "RCA Pending Found"
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim instances As Long

    instances = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("AB"), "RCA Pending")

    MsgBox "We Found " & instances & " instances of RCA Pending(s)", _
    vbInformation, "RCA Pending Found"
End Sub
```